# Android: Require variable accessed from one thread to be immediately available in another

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization

I'm developing an OpenGL ES 2.0 game and have run into a problem which I hope is really simple to resolved.

Basically within my game I am using the 2 threads provided by OpenGL only.  Those being:

- Rendering thread
- UI Thread

I'll try to explain with a simple example:

So, on my **UI thread**, in my **onTouchEvent** method, I'm doing somethink like this *(Includes some pseudocode)*:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    actionMask = event.getActionMasked();
    pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();  
    pointerID = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);       

    switch (actionMask){

           //Primary pointer down
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { 

                  if (exitIsPressed){
                      renderer.gameIsPaused = false; //User has exited game, so reset this flag
                      Log.v("Tag","gameIsPaused Value is (from UI Thread): "+renderer.gameIsPaused);
                  }
           }
}
```

And then on my **Rendering thread**, I'm using the variable like so:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    Log.v("Tag","gameIsPaused Value is (from Rendering Thread): "+gameIsPaused);

}
```

So, 'renderer' is my GLSurfaceView and the 'gameIsPaused' boolean flag is a member of the GLSurfaceView class.  I'm simply trying to update it from my UI Thread.

When I run the code and press the exit button, I *sometimes*, get this:

> gameIsPaused Value is (from UI Thread): False
>
> gameIsPaused Value is (from Rendering Thread): True

The code here is simplified, but I hope it explains the issue.  I'm guessing this is to do with both threads accessing the same variable, however, I'm really unsure how to get around this.  Most of the posts I've seen when searching for this kind of problem within a set up like this seem to focus on synchronization between rendering and *updating* threads, however, as you can see, I'm only using one thread for rendering *and* updating, so my question relates specifically to making sure the variables are immediately available to the rendering thread after some action is carried out on them on the UI thread.

I've attempted to mark the gameIsPaused variable as volatile, however, this made no difference.

Hope someone can explain how this works, what I should be doing to avoid this problem and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the two threads run in parallel but operation order **between different threads** isn't guaranteed, any thread can be interrupted at any time making the logs print seemingly out-of-order:

1. Rendering thread reads the gameIsPaused variable value (`true`)
2. Rendering thread prepares the string "gameIsPaused Value is (from Rendering Thread): True"
3. **thread switch**
4. UI thread sets the gameIsPaused variable to `false`
5. UI thread prepares the string "gameIsPaused Value is (from Rendering Thread): False"
6. UI thread prints its string
7. **thread switch**
8. Rendering thread prints its string

Other possibility:

1. Rendering thread reads the gameIsPaused variable value (`true`)
2. **thread switch**
3. UI thread sets the gameIsPaused variable to `false`
4. UI thread prepares the string "gameIsPaused Value is (from Rendering Thread): False"
5. UI thread prints its string
6. **thread switch**
7. Rendering thread prepares the string "gameIsPaused Value is (from Rendering Thread): True" from register value
8. Rendering thread prints its string

If you need to set multiple variables at the same time without the render thread running while those variables are set you need to use a **mutex** to prevent the rendering thread from running while you change the variables.

Another option is to set a single variable in the UI thread and have the rendering thread do the work of setting the multiple variables.

A third option is to prepare a message object and send it to the rendering thread using a message queue so the rendering thread acts on this as a single operation.

Any of these will make sure the rendering thread does not see an in-between state with some variables updated and some with their old values.

Comment: Many thanks @StephaneHockenhull, interesting. When you say use a mutex are you talking about using a synchronised block?  Also, please could you explain the 2nd option, I don't quite get what you mean by "multiple variables" - I'm only updating a single variable?  And re the third option, I'm guessing you mean something like queueEvent?  Is it possible to edit your answer to show some brief code examples so I can better understand, thanks - appreicate your help!

Comment: In this case yes, a synchronized block would probably suffice.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneHockenhull, I'll try to enclose the access to the variable inside a synchronised block